# Adding impact factor information into apalike.bst

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I am trying to add impact factor information into the apalike.bst. So far, I changed the apalike.bst as follows

Firstly, I added `impact_factor` into the `ENTRY` section and created a new function

```
FUNCTION {format.impactFactor}
{ 
impact_factor empty$
    { "" }
    {"( Impact Factor:" impact_factor ")"}
  if$
}
```

This function is then called from the `article` function

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output              
  output.year.check                 
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { journal emphasize "journal" output.check
      format.vol.num.pages output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  format.impactFactor output              % <---- the new filed
  new.block  
  note output
  fin.entry  
}
```

I get the following error message when trying to compile it using bibtex and a valid bib file

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: apubs.aux
The style file: apalike_custom.bst
Database file #1: JanS.bib
ptr=2, stack=
( Impact Factor:
45(1):205--212
---the literal stack isn't empty for entry ferkl2010ceiling
while executing---line 1104 of file apalike_custom.bst
(There was 1 error message)
```

Answer (score 3):

You want the function to output *one* string, so you have to concatenate them:

```
FUNCTION {format.impactFactor}
{ 
impact_factor empty$
    { "" }
    {"( Impact Factor:" impact_factor * ")" *}
  if$
}
```

Comment: I tried this and got an error "You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry" for every entry in my bib file...

Comment: I also get an error "impact_factor is an unknown function" in the two lines in the bst file that mention the impact_factor.